# Kernel density estimate plot is not appearing in Jupyter notebook output when running seaborn.histplot()

Tags: python, seaborn, jupyter, kernel-density, probability-density

I am trying to plot a probability density function (PDF) and approaching this through adding a kernel density estimate (KDE) to smooth my histogram by using `seaborn.histplot()`.

```
sns.histplot(data=np.reshape(eddy_model_ds.q.isel(lev=0).values, (-1)), stat='density', kde=True)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.xlabel(r'$q_{1}$ [$s^{-1}$]')
plt.ylabel('probability density')
plt.title('Upper PV PDF')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I'm expecting to get something like this where the curve is plotted with the histogram:
[image]

However this is what gets outputted when I run the above code in Jupyter notebook. The KDE curve is not actually getting plotted along with the histogram.
[image]

Would anyone be able to provide any insight as to why this is happening?

I've already tried adding `%matplotlib inline` with my imports as well in the case that there was an issue with `seaborn` sending plots outside of the Jupyter notebook. I've also tried running the other various methods similar to `histplot()` instead, including `displot()` and `kdeplot()`, however the curve fails to show when using these also.

Comment: This depends on the version of seaborn. For older versions you might need `sns.distplot` instead of `sns.histplot`  (note the `t` in dis**t**plot).

Comment: @JohanC , I went ahead and tried using `sns.distplot` instead however it is still only showing the histogram plot and not the density curve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was using version v0.11.0 of `seaborn` and I just updated to the latest version (v0.12.1) and the KDE plot is now appearing.